# cant get ab test to work with gzip

Tags: nginx, stress-testing, apachebench

this is my nginx gzip config:

```
 gzip on;
     gzip_vary on;
     gzip_proxied any;
     gzip_comp_level 4;
     gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

I approve that it works by all the gzip testing websites that confirim my site is service gzip
my is simple html file that its content type is `Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8`

my page content without gzip is 300kb and with gzip should be 20kb
tried run all the options like:

```
ab  -r -n 200 -c 10 -k -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" http://example.com
ab  -r -n 200 -c 10 -k -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" http://example.com
ab  -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -n 200 -c 10 -k  http://example.com
ab  -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -n 200 -c 10 -k  http://example.com
```

etc
no matter what I always get in the sum `Document Length:        183675 bytes`
which mean its not getting the gzip version which should be much smaller.

any idea how to get it work? I am trying to stress test my website but I am always get limited by my Network Out speed which is only 250 Mbps, and cpu and ram only 10% max when I reach the limit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

so I needed to add to the nginx config

```
gzip_http_version 1.0;
```

the default which is 1.1 was not good I guess for apachebench